# Circular function with arbitrary radius and center

Tags: functions, special-functions, fourier-analysis

I'm looking for an implementation in Mathematica of the generalized circular function $\text{circ}(x, y; R, c)$ of radius $R$ and centre $c=(c_1,c_2)$ such that

$$\text{circ}(x, y; R, c)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }\sqrt{(x_1-c_1)^2+(x_2-c_2)^2}\le R, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

In particular, I am interested in a form that allows me to compute the Fourier transform in terms of Bessel functions. What is a possible implementation?

Comment: `Boole@RegionMember[Disk[{c1, c2}, R], {x1, x2}]`

Comment: @Syed How do you compute its transform? This doesn't depend on $x$ or $y$.

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Please ignore.

Comment: @Syed I want some function `F[x1_,x_2,c_1,c_2,R]` that is $1$ inside the circle (or on the circumference thereof), and $0$ elsewhere. There has to be an explicit dependence on the coordinates $x_1,x_2$, otherwise there would be no way to act on it with the Fourier transform (I think).

Comment: Yours is a *disk*, not a *circle*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork True.

Answer (score 1):

Function definition

```
F[x1_, x2_, c1_, c2_, R_] := Which[  R >= 0 && (c1 - x1)^2 + (c2 - x2)^2 <= R^2, 1, True, 0]

Plot3D[F[x1, x2, 1, 1/2, 1], {x1, -1, 3}, {x2, -1, 2}  ]
```

[image]

**first addendum**

Mathematica v12.2 evaluates wrong result for the Fouriertransform

```
FourierTransform[UnitStep[R^2 - (   (x1 - c1)^2 + (x2 - c2)^2  )] , {x1, x2}, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2}, 
Assumptions -> {Element[{R, c1, c2}, Reals], R > 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

Numerical evaluation of a special gives (takes some time...)

```
    With[{c1 = 1/2, c2 = 1/4, R = 1}, 
 reg = ImplicitRegion[(x1 - c1)^2 + (x2 - c2)^2 <= R^2, {x1, x2}];
 ft[\[Omega]1_?NumericQ, \[Omega]2_?NumericQ] := 
  1/(2 Pi) NIntegrate[
    UnitStep[R^2 - (   (x1 - c1)^2 + (x2 - c2)^2  )] Exp[
      I (x1 \[Omega]1 + x2 \[Omega]2 )], Element[{x1, x2}, reg] ];
  {Plot3D[Re@ft[om1, om2], {om1, -10, 10}, {om2, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot3D[Im@ft[om1, om2], {om1, -10, 10}, {om2, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

**second addendum**

Introducing polarcoordinates `x1->c1+r Cos[phi],x2->c1+r Sin[phi]` it is possible to evaluate the FourierTransform analytically

Fouriertransform `1/(2 Pi) \[Integral]Exp[I (x1 \[Omega]1 +x2 \[Omega]2 )] dx1 dx2` transforms to

```
ft= 1/(2 Pi) Integrate[r Exp[I  (   \[Omega]1 (c1 + r   Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]) + \[Omega]2 (c2 +r  Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]))], {r, 0, R}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
Assumptions ->Element[{r, R, \[Omega]1, \[Omega]2}, Reals]] // Simplify
```

[image]

Result confirms the numerical example

```
With[{c1 = 1/2, c2 = 1/4, 
  R = 1},  {Plot3D[
   Re@(1/2 E^(I (c1 \[Omega]1 + c2 \[Omega]2))
       R^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
       2, -(1/4) R^2 (\[Omega]1^2 + \[Omega]2^2)]), {\[Omega]1, -10, 
    10}, {\[Omega]2, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot3D[Im@(1/2 E^(I (c1 \[Omega]1 + c2 \[Omega]2))
       R^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
       2, -(1/4) R^2 (\[Omega]1^2 + \[Omega]2^2)]), {\[Omega]1, -10, 
    10}, {\[Omega]2, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Do you also get the transform? My machine seems to have trouble with the computation.

Comment: @Noobgrammer I tried `FourierTransform[
 UnitStep[R^2 - (   (x1 - c1)^2 + (x2 - c2)^2  )] , {x1, 
  x2}, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2}, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[{R, c1, c2}, Reals], R > 0}]` but Mathematica v12.2 evaluates wrong result `0`!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (hopefully better) attempt, but first tackle a simpler case as a demo of the workflow.

```
p1 = Plot3D[HeavisidePi[1/2 (x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
   , PlotStyle -> Darker@Cyan
   , ImageSize -> 300
   , AxesLabel -> Automatic
   , Exclusions -> All
   , ExclusionsStyle -> HatchShading[.4, Darker@Cyan]
   , SphericalRegion -> True
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
   ];

FourierTransform[
  FunctionExpand@HeavisidePi[1/2 (x^2 + y^2)], {x, 
   y}, {ω1, ω2}] // FunctionExpand
```

$\frac{I_1\left(\sqrt{-\text{$\omega $1}^2-\text{$\omega $2}^2}\right)}{\sqrt{-\text{$\omega $1}^2-\text{$\omega $2}^2}}$

```
p2 = Plot3D[BesselI[1, Sqrt[-ω1^2 - ω2^2]]/
   Sqrt[-ω1^2 - ω2^2]
   , {ω1, -10, 10}
   , {ω2, -10, 10}
   , PlotStyle -> ColorData["HTML", "Aquamarine"]
   , PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0.6}
   , ImageSize -> 300
   , AxesLabel -> Automatic
   , PlotPoints -> 20
   , MaxRecursion -> 2
   , SphericalRegion -> True
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
   ];

Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
```

---

[image]

---

**Comments on the more general case**

Using a function with a disk of radius R and situated at an offset:

```
f[x_, y_, c1_, c2_, R_] := 
 UnitBox[(1/(2 R^2)) ((x - c1)^2 + (y - c2)^2)]
```

Instead of the `HeavisidePi`, I am using `UnitBox` as advised by @user64494 with a correction to the formula suggested by @UlrichNewmann. Thanks to both.

---

While computing the Fourier transform, this evaluates instantly but with `c1=0` and `c2=0`. Note that the radius can be set differently.

```
FourierTransform[
  f[x, y, 0, 0, 1], {x, y}, {ω1, ω2}] // FunctionExpand
```

A workaround (check!) can be to add an offset to `ω1` and `ω2` after the transform calculation in order to shift the center of the 3D sinc-like plot. As an example:

```
FourierTransform[
   Evaluate@f[x, y, 0, 0, 3], {x, 
    y}, {ω1, ω2}] /. {ω1 -> ω1 - 
     1, ω2 -> ω2 - 1/2 } // FunctionExpand
```

I cannot comment on its math correctness so you can check or devise another strategy to evaluate the Fourier transform. I am not aware of such a strategy at this point. Perhaps the transform will evaluate after several minutes more and I haven't waited for more than five minutes on my machine before quitting the calculation.

Comment: The right function in this situation is `UnitBox` instead of `HeavisidePi`. The  `HeavisidePi` is an attempt (which leaves much to be desired) to implement the certain distribution in Mathematica,  whereas `UnitBox` is a usual function.

Comment: Thanks @user64494. The Fourier transform exhibits the same difficulty with computation, but your point is taken.

Comment: There is a bug in the two-dimensional `FourierTransform`: `f[x_, y_, c1_, c2_, R_] := 
 FunctionExpand@UnitStep[1/(2  R)  ((x - c1)^2 + (y - c2)^2)];ourierTransform[
 Evaluate@f[x, y, 0, 0, 3], {x, y}, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2}]` produces `2 \[Pi] DiracDelta[\[Omega]1] DiracDelta[\[Omega]2]` though this is a usual Fourier transform of a usual function. `InverseFourierTransform[%, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2}, {x, y}]` results in `1`.

Comment: [CASE:5115048] has been submitted by me.

Comment: Many thanks, @user64494.

Comment: @Syed: Is the definition of `f` correct? I would expect `f[x_, y_, c1_, c2_, R_] :=  
 UnitStep[R^2 - (   (x - c1)^2 + (y - c2)^2  )]`

Comment: Thanks @UlrichNeumann, I have added `R^2`.